# One step analysis in Poisson Processes

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, poisson-process

[image]

Dear all,

I'd be very glad if you could help me understand something about the one step analysis. In the attached picture $PP(\lambda)$ means a Poisson Process of rate $\lambda$, and $\tilde X_s = X_{T_1+s}-1$ where $T_1$ is the first arrival time of $X$.

The only thing I can't understand is why can we restrict the integral of the expectation to the interval $[0, u]$, i.e. why is the expected value on $[u, \infty)$ of the independent Poisson Process equal to $0$

**Edit** I think I know what's going on: If $t > u$, then we are still not having the first arrival, hence the expectation is $0$. Is that the case?

Comment: What does $\tilde X$ denote here?

Comment: $\tilde{X}_{s} = X_{T_1+s} - 1$, the independent PP

Comment: I added that to the question so it is more clear, thanks. And yes, if $t>u$ then clearly $\mathbb E[X_u\mid T_1=t]=0$.